# Select2 is duplicating my dropdown list

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, flask, jquery-select2

Select2 is duplicating my dropdown list so I have both the original select list and also the select2 select box, I have been unable to recreate it outside of my project so it could be an import perhaps, has anybody experienced anything similar before or know what imports could be causing it? The only information I could find was on jquery growfield which I do not have. Thanks!

**HTML**

```
<p class="form-control input-lg"><label for="industry">Industry</label>:
    <select class="industry" id="industry" name="industry">
        <option value="Select" selected="selected"></option>
        {% for industry in industries %}
            <option value="{{ industry }}">{{ industry }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
</p>
```

**JQuery**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
     $("#industry").select2();
     $
 });
```

Comment: Do you have multiple `<select>` elements on the same page with that id? Typically the cause here is from Select2 being cloned, or from there actually being multiple copies. You may want to check your JS console, as it could have some information as to why Select2 didn't hide the original.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out that the issue was caused by my use of css on the original list element.
`Select2` works by applying the class `select2-hidden-accessible` to the actual select field I wrote.

That class has CSS that, among other things, shrinks the original select field to 1px width so it is not visible.
Then it renders its own `span` classes that have the `select2` functionality based on the content from the original select element.

CSS on `.form_inputs select{}` was overriding this shrinking to `1px width`.

Comment: so what did you change to your code to make it working as you wish?

Answer (score 1):

It's old but always useful !

I forgot to import the CSS for select2... That was why it didn't work and displayed the select twice.

I hope it'll be helpful !

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered a same situation with my Select2 where only the first dropdown is functional, while the duplicated dropdowns created during forward and backward browser navigation are not working. To address this issue, I've opted to remove all additional dropdowns, keeping only the first one. I've then utilized the 'popstate' event.

The popstate event of the Window interface is triggered when the active history entry changes during user navigation through the session history. This event adjusts the current history entry to match the last page the user visited, or, if applicable, the history entry.

```
$(window).on('popstate', function(event) {
   $('.select2-container:not(:first)').remove();
   });
```