# Select2 - is duplicating when i use clone function

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, jquery-select2

I have seen this question [jQuery Select2 duplicating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31794592/select2-is-duplicating-my-dropdown-list), but not work for me.

When i click in plus button this function running

```
$("#novo-insumo").click(function(){
        var novoID = $(".insumo-row").length;

        var elementCloned = $("#insumo-row")
                .clone();
        elementCloned.find('#insumo-select0').attr('id', "insumo-select" + novoID);

        $("#insumo-tbody")
            .find("select")
            // call destroy to revert the changes made by Select2
            .select2("destroy")
            .end()
            .append(
                elementCloned

        );
        // enable Select2 on the select elements
        $("#insumo-tbody").find("select").select2({
            placeholder: "digite",
            "language": {
               "noResults": function(){
                   return "Nenhum resultado encontrado";
               }
            }
        });




    });
```

But the result not is that i want.

[image: form]

I'm using select2-4.0.2 version.

Comment: `But the result not is that i want`. Fine. What do you want? You are duplicating not only elements, ids too. ID attribute must be unique in the same html document. Don't duplicate ids and should work.

Comment: I want to duplicate the row with inputs. I change the ids with elementCloned.find('#insumo-select0').attr('id', "insumo-select" + novoID);

Comment: Share a working example reproducing the issue. You can use stacksnippets or jsfiddle.net.